# Indent entire yield output 2 spaces in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting

For the sake of good looking code, is there some way to add a tab of spacing across the entire layout `<%= yield %>` in Ruby on Rails? Here's what I mean:

**THIS:**

```
# layout.html.erb
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

**PLUS THIS:**

```
# page.html.erb
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

**OUTPUTS:**

```
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
<p>Hello, world!</p>
</body>
```

**WHAT I REALLY WANT TO OUTPUT:**

```
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</body>
```

I did some research and found that using a minus sign like `<%= yield -%>` removes indentation, but I couldn't find a way to add it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
# layout.html.erb
<body>
<%= yield.gsub(/^/, "  ") %>
</body>
```

---

Actually, I have a method `String#indent` in my own library such as:

```
class String
  def indent s = "\t"; gsub(/^/, s) end
end
```

Using this, you can reuse it in various places.

```
# layout.html.erb
<body>
<%= yield.indent %>
</body>
```

Comment: Very nice, did the trick. Is it still somehow possible to indent that yield in `layout.html.erb` and bring the first line of the yield output back by 2 spaces?

Comment: What happens if you do `<%= yield.gsub(/^/, "  ") -%>`?

Comment: I still had 2 spaces of formatting on my `<%= yield %>` in `layout.html.erb` (which I wanted), and it was adding an extra 2 spaces of formatting to the output. I just fixed it by adding the minus sign like I mentioned before: `<%= yield.gsub(/^/, " ") -%>`. Yep, just like your edit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Sawa's answer, I just found a slightly more flexible approach to indenting content. Whilst Sawa's method above works just fine, it doesn't push out your yield code enough spaces if you're dealing with multiple block levels before your `<%= yield %>`.

Here's a slight improvement that can be customized to specific needs:

```
class String
  def indent(spaces)
    num = (" " * spaces)
    gsub(/^/, num)
  end
end
```

Now you can specify how many spaces of indentation you need right from your layouts like so:

```
# layout.html.erb
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <%= yield.indent(4) -%>
  </div>
</body>
```

The above example will apply 4 spaces of indentation to every line of your yield. If there was another level, you would make change it to 6 and so on...

Comment: If you have multiple levels of nesting, the way to do it is using the `indent` method for each call level. The lines to which `indent` had applied multiple times would be indented as many levels. You do not have to control the depth manually. My version of `indent` is meant to take the single-level tab sequence as an optional argument (`"\t"` for some people, `"  "` for others, etc.) to meet different coding conventions.